# Chrome predefined email UTF-8 issue

Tags: google-chrome, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, html-entities

I have predefined email buttons on my [website project](https://www.deutsch-vietnamesisch-dolmetscher.com/kontakt/). The issue is behind the click on the green contact button with the German linktext "Jetzt eine E-Mail an den vietnamesisch Übersetzer schreiben!".

In Firefox and Internet Explorer all characters are encoded correctly within the predefined mail. When I click in Chrome on the same contact button, then the predefined text is not showing up correctly, all German special characters are damaged and are not well encoded as UTF-8. Do you have an idea to solve this?

Example: fÃ¼r RÃ¼ckfragen

The html file itself is saved as UTF-8 without BOM in notepad++.

htaccess is configured:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

HTML Code for the link button with predefined email:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary green" href="mailto:&#x69;&#x6e;&#x66;&#x6f;&#x40;&#x64;&#x65;&#x75;&#x74;&#x73;&#x63;&#x68;&#x2d;&#x76;&#x69;&#x65;&#x74;&#x6e;&#x61;&#x6d;&#x65;&#x73;&#x69;&#x73;&#x63;&#x68;&#x2d;&#x64;&#x6f;&#x6c;&#x6d;&#x65;&#x74;&#x73;&#x63;&#x68;&#x65;&#x72;&#x2e;&#x63;&#x6f;&#x6d;?subject=Anfrage%20&#220;bersetzung&amp;body=Hallo%20Frau%20Dang,%0A%0Aim%20Anhang%20befindet%20sich%20meine%20zu%20&#252;bersetzende%20Datei.%0AIch%20ben&#246;tige%20die%20&#252;bersetzte%20Datei%20zur&#252;ck%20bis%20zum%20folgenden%20Termin:%0A%0ABitte%20schicken%20Sie%20mir%20einen%20unverbindlichen%20Kostenvoranschlag%20zu.%0AMeine%20Telefonnummer%20für%20eventuelle%20Rückfragen%20lautet:%0A%0AMeine%20vollst&#228;ndige%20Adresse%20für%20den%20Postversand%20lautet%20(optional):%0A%0AVielen%20Dank!%0A%0AMit%20freundlichen%20Gr&#252;&#223;en%0A%0A">Jetzt eine E-Mail an den <i>vietnamesisch Übersetzer</i> schreiben!</a>
```

Comment: So what exactly does your email link look like?

Comment: I added the code example